# Reading a 2-dimensional array of char in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I'm trying to read an M*N array of chars, but I get some weird characters when printing the array. I couldn't figure out what's wrong with the code, what am I missing here?

```
int i,j,m,n;
char mat[10][10]
printf("N=");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("M=");
scanf("%d", &m);
fflush(stdin);
// Read array elements, one by one
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        printf("mat[%d][%d]=", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%c", &mat[i][j]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
// Print matrix
putchar('\n');
for (i=0; i<n; i++);
{
    for (j=0; j<m; j++)
        printf("%2c", mat[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Example input/output:

```
N=2
M=2
mat[1][1]=1
mat[1][2]=A
mat[2][1]=2
mat[2][2]=B

 ╥ ⌠
1
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour. Whether that's your problem depends on what implementation you use. Also, what weird characters are printed out?

Comment: I added fflush(stdin) because there's still a newline character in the input stream sometimes and this may interfere with scanf().

Comment: I guessed that. But as I said, it's undefined behaviour, and it doesn't work everywhere. Adding a space to the format string to skip initial whitespace would be a possibility if you don't want to accept whitespace as input. If you do, you would have to clear the input buffer until the newline with a `getchar()` loop if you want it portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char mat[10][10]` -> `char mat[10][10];`

`for (i=0; i<n; i++);` -> `for (i=0; i<n; i++)`

```
/* delete
for (i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
    for (j=0; j<i+1; j++)
        printf("%c ", mat[i][j]);
*/
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem..the extra semicolon. That last you told me to delete is part of another task, I forgot to take it out before pasting it here.

Answer (score 2):

your

```
scanf("%c", &mat[i][j]);
```

is catching the newlines. add white space at the beginning of the format

```
scanf(" %c", &mat[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (void)
{
        int i,j,m,n;
        char mat[10][10];
        char ch;
        printf("N=");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("M=");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        // Read array elements, one by one
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
                for (j=0; j<m; j++)
                {
                        printf("mat[%d][%d]=", i, j);
                        //Flush standard inputs
                        while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
                        {
                        }
                        mat[i][j]=getchar();
                        printf("\n");
                }
        }
        printf("printing %d x %d matrix", n , m);
        // Print matrix
        putchar('\n');
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
                for (j=0; j<m; j++)
                {
                        printf("mat[%d][%d]=", i, j);
                        putchar(mat[i][j]);
                        printf("\n");
                }
        }
return (0);
}
```